# I can't access specific indexes of my array php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, string

I can't access specific indexes of my array, I want access to the third index of the array that actually holds the zip code of the user to use it in a SELECT statement. Here's the array:

```
$zip_code = connecting::query('SELECT zipcode FROM accounts WHERE username=:user_name', array(':user_name' => $user_name));
$zipcode = json_encode($zip_code, true);
```

Here's the output when I print `$zipcode`:

```
[{"zipcode":"28262","0":"28262"}]
```

But when I print $zipcode[2] nothing prints and I can't use it. I can't just access it directly like that? I have used json_encode, var_export, implode, etc. to try to just convert it to a string but it doesn't work.

Here's the query method that I call:

```
public static function query($query,$params = array())
{


    $statement = self :: db()->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute($params);
    if(explode(' ',$query)[0] == 'SELECT')
    {
        $data = $statement->fetchAll();
        return $data;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you encode your data to json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fetchAll` returns **array of arrays**. So, if you `print_r(zip_code);` you will see something like:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [zipcode] => 28262 
        [0] => 28262 
    ) 
)
```

So, as you can see - there's no key with index `2` here, only `0` in the outer array and two keys `0` and `zipcode` in the subarray.

Also, as you can see your data (`28262`) is duplicated in the subarray under different keys. To avoid this you can provide argument to [`fetchAll`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php):

```
$data = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```